# Restart Mac without having to enter password

Tags: passwords, mamp, restart

Every time I start or restart my Mac running Yosemite, MAMP forces me to enter my admin user name and password first. Is there a way to bypass this? I don't want to have to enter my credentials every time I restart or quit MAMP.

Comment: Well, according to the docs, this is caused by using the "standard" apache port of 80. However, I have my port set to the MAMP default 8888, and I am still asked for my password. Strangely enough, it's not when I start the servers, only when I close them.

Answer (score 0):

MAMP needs to be run with the administrative privilages.

So, if you quit the MAMP and want to start it again, also if your are not on the administrator account using the MAMP.

It will request the admin password.

The same explanation works where you are saying that, if you start or restart your Mac you are getting a prompt for admin password to start the MAMP.

- Use the administrator account for using the MAMP.

Please provide more details if your question doesn't get resolved.

For the user's who doesn't know what the MAMP is you can refer https://bitnami.com/stack/mamp